# Remove custom taxonomy column from my custom post type columns

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using wp 3.5 i have a custom post `(sp_product)` and also i have custom taxonomy. I want to remove that custom taxonomy filter column but i don't want to make `'show_admin_column' => false`.

I wanna unset from `$columns['']` .

How should i do that ? i also want to add some css/js when it will show in column and top select menu. (showing in this image like)

[image]

Comment: Probably, unsetting the column will be as easy as adding one: in `manage_edit-CPT_columns` and `unset($columns['CUSTOM-TAXONOMY'])`, have you tried it? ::: Can you clarify this: *"add some css/js when it will show in column and top select menu"*, I don't understand even with the screenshot...

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. In that picture using chosen (jQuery plugin) so i want to use that kind of js/css in my filter menu. so, how should i do that, where should i put those js/css cods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide columns in a Custom Post Type screen, you need the filter `manage_{$this->screen->id}_columns`.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-sp_product_columns', 'hide_cpt_columns_so_14257172' );

function hide_cpt_columns_so_14257172( $columns )
{
    // Change categories for your custom taxonomy
    unset($columns['categories']);
    return $columns;
}
```

To add custom CSS/Javascript in a specific screen, you can use the action `admin_head-$hook_suffix`. The following code hides the <kbd>Show all dates</kbd>, <kbd>View all categories</kbd> and <kbd>Filter</kbd> elements:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'custom_css_js_so_14257172' );

function custom_css_js_so_14257172() 
{
    // Apply only in the correct CPT, otherwise it would print in Pages/Posts
    global $current_screen;
    if( 'sp_product' != $current_screen->post_type)
        return;
    ?>
        <style>
            select[name="m"] { display:none }
            select[id="cat"] { display:none }
            #post-query-submit { display:none }
        </style>
    <?php
}
```